# IdentityServer4 Quickstart UI only runs with SDK, but doesn't work with runtime

Tags: identityserver4

I've set up an IdentityServer4 server which runs if I do a `dotnet run` in the main project directory, but does not run correctly if I publish it and then try to run the dll with dotnet:

```
dotnet publish
cd bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish
dotnet MyIdentityServer.dll
```

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.2. I've tried both in my regular dev environment as well as using the SDK and runtime docker containers. It works using the SDK in both my regular environment and the SDK container. It does not work when using the runtime in either my regular dev environment or inside of a runtime container.

When I do the dotnet run, I can see the web UI for IdentityServer but when I run the published DLL, the startup doesn't have the same IdentityServer startup messages and after it says it's running, I can't connect to the server on the port it says should be running.

Here's what the startup messages look like when it is working after doing a `dotnet run`:

```
MacBook-Pro:MyIdentityServer XXXXXXXXXX$ dotnet run
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Starting IdentityServer4 version 2.3.2.0
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using the default authentication scheme idsrv for IdentityServer
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/Projects/FirstIdentityServer4/src/MyIdentityServer
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Here's what the startup messages look like when it's not working after running the published DLL directly with a `dotnet MyIdentityServer.dll`:

```
MacBook-Pro:publish XXXXXXXXXXXX$ dotnet MyIdentityServer.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /Users/XXXXXXXXXXX/Projects/FirstIdentityServer4/src/MyIdentityServer/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Here's my project directory:

```
MacBook-Pro:MyIdentityServer XXXXXXXXX$ ls
Config.cs           appsettings.Development.json
Dockerfile          appsettings.json
MyIdentityServer.csproj     bin
Program.cs          obj
Properties          something.txt
Quickstart          tempkey.rsa
Startup.cs          wwwroot
Views
```

Here's my publish directory after doing a `dotnet publish`:

```
MacBook-Pro:publish XXXXXXXXXX$ ls
IdentityModel.dll           MyIdentityServer.pdb
IdentityServer4.Storage.dll     MyIdentityServer.runtimeconfig.json
IdentityServer4.dll         appsettings.Development.json
MyIdentityServer.Views.dll      appsettings.json
MyIdentityServer.Views.pdb      tempkey.rsa
MyIdentityServer.deps.json      web.config
MyIdentityServer.dll            wwwroot
```

Am I publishing it incorrectly or running it incorrectly?

Comment: try **dotnet run -c Release** in **Dev** environment

Comment: do you still need help ?

Comment: When I do a `dotnet run -c Release` it's using the SDK from the project directory as opposed to using the runtime from the publish directory. Any call to `dotnet run` fails in an environment that only has the dotnet core runtime. So yeah, still looking for an answer. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21

Comment: are using AddDeveloperSigningCredential can you add startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

base on

```
MacBook-Pro:MyIdentityServer XXXXXXXXXX$ dotnet run
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
Hosting environment: Development
```

and this

```
MacBook-Pro:publish XXXXXXXXXXXX$ dotnet MyIdentityServer.dll
Hosting environment: Production
```

the logs

```
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
```

is usually  from

```
services.AddIdentityServer();
```

so i amuse that you are calling AddIdentityServer inside IsDevelopment

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddIdentityServer();
}
```

that why Hosting environment: Production
is not getting IdentityServer  logs

Comment: No that was not it. services.AddIdentityServer() is up at teh top level of that method. 

I have a little more info... I can get to .well-known/openid-configuration, but can't get to the quickstart UI. So I guess I should clarify my original statement and I'll fix the title... The quickstart UI is readily available when doing a "dotnet run" from the project dir, but it isn't available in the published app. I'll post this in the IdentityServer4 repo too.